# How to make zsh fail the whole line when a command substitution fails?

Tags: zsh, command-substitution

If I do:

```
$(blah) bleh
```

I get

```
zsh: command not found: blah
zsh: command not found: bleh
```

This has me a little worried, because it means that zsh is executing `bleh` which was never intended to be a command; what if it happens to be executable and does something I didn't want?

Is there a way to make the whole line fail the moment `blah` fails?

Answer (score 2):

The reason `bleh` is tried is, that `$(blah)` gets replaced by an empty string if `blah` does not exists. In which case `bleh` will be the first word on the completely parsed command line and thus used interpreted as command.

So you have to catch the empty string and prevent further execution. Thankfully ZSH has a Parameter Expansion, namely `${name:?word}` that can be used just for that case:

```
${$(blah):?No such thing} bleh
```

If `blah` does not exist, ZSH will print `No such thing` and return to the prompt (or exit the shell, if it is non-interactive):

```
zsh: : No such thing
```

else it will just the substituted command

```
% alias blah="echo echo '>>>'"
% ${$(blah):?No such thing} bleh
>>> bleh
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `&&` to separate commands will terminate on failure:

`$(blah) && bleh`

Comment: I'm actually not looking to separate the commands, but to execute it as a single command. Like for example `$(echo cat) /dev/null`.